# Spring Data find substring containing special characters

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to retrieve data from elasticsearch containing special characters like **. / -** ... using spring data ?

I have document defined like this:

```
@Document(indexName = "audit-2018.135", type = "audit")
public class Trace {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String uri;

    // setters & getters
}
```

I need to retrieve data from elasticSearch by field **uri**.

Here's an example how data looks:

> martin-int-vip.vs.cz:5080/kib/api/runtime/case/CASE0000000000324223

When using kibana I can use:

> uri: "martin-int-vip.vs.cz:5080/kib"

and I get back the record above which contains desired substring.

Now I need to achieve the same from java however in spring data it's not working as expected.

I have elasticSearchRepository defined like this:

```
public interface TraceRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Trace, String> {    
    List<Trace> findByUriContaining(String uri);
}
```

when I call method **findByUriContaining** with parameter **uri** as:

> martin-int-vip.vs.cz:5080\/kib

or even this

> martin-int

I get back 0 results. When I send "kib" as parameter it returns correctly all records containing word "kib" however it's not working with special characters like . / - etc. How should I query my elasticSearch from java to get all records which contains my desired substring ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that by default elasticSearch analyzer tokenize your query. Instead of "martin-int-vip.vs.cz:5080/kib" it looks for a field which contains martin and int and vip...

In order to query these kind of fields you need to change behaviour of analyzer or you can use **elasticSearchTemplate** and Criteria to build more flexible queries.

Comment: I am in this exact situation, where I need to search for terms as "I+D". Could you share how you modified the analyzer? Thanks!